# How to override created_at field in model when importing a CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm importing a CSV full of waitlist signups into my database with previous created dates, how can I import them while keeping their initial dates vs. having them all show the same date of importing?

I get the error: `Rails can't mass-assign protected attributes for id, created_at`

The code:

```
 csv_file = params[:csv][:file].read
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_file, :headers => false) 
    csv.each do |row|
       Model.create!(:email => row[0], :created_at => row[1])    
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the desired column to the `attr_accessible`

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at
end
```

Comment: Just be sure to check mass assignment vulnerabilities, [here](http://launchware.com/articles/whats-new-in-edge-scoped-mass-assignment-in-rails-3-1) is a good post

Comment: Since Rails 4 changes to control access via the controller instead of the model this answer is out of date. We no longer use attr_accesible and (!) it should "just work"

Answer (score 17):

In Rails 4:

`attr_accessible` is no longer used and including it a the top of a model will likely break your code. Merely including `:created_at` in the args passed to `create!` should do it.

Turning @Ghoti's comment into an answer here to give it more visibility

Comment: Confirmed - just add `created_at` as an argument works in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
csv.each do |row|
   doc = Model.create!(:email => row[0])
   doc.update(created_at: row[1])
end
```

---

I needed to do something similar, going back through organizations, and updating the creation based on the earliest user that registered (if applicable). (The organization ID was a custom string :-)

So you can see how the `update` command works... And you can see the **clever trick** to use a BSON id to get the date.

```
Org.all.to_a.collect do |o|
  u = o.users.first
  if u
    o.update(created_at: Time.parse(u.id.generation_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')))
  else
    o.update(created_at: Time.now.utc)
  end
end
```