# Model create overrides custom params :created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, timestamp

I am uploading legacy articles to my Rails app. I am sending `created_at` as a parameter in my request as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34584330/6174302). However, this attribute seemingly is not passed "through". I can `puts(params[:created_at])` and see my custom `created_at`, yet in the logs the article is INSERTed with a `created_at` of the current timestamp.

Here is my articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  ...
  # POST /articles
  def create
    @section = Section.friendly.find(params[:section_id])
    # Can't let people publish by default
    @article = @section.articles.build(
      article_params.merge(is_published: false)
    )

   if @article.save
      render json: @article, status: :created, location: @article
   else
      render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
 end
end
```

My request is:

```
 http POST :3000/articles title='example' section_id=1 content="<p>the section exists.</p>" slug="example" created_at="2017-06-109T17:57:55.149-05:00"
```

The logs:

```
Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-24 12:05:06 -0500
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"title"=>"example", "section_id"=>"1", "content"=>"<p>the section exists.</p>", "slug"=>"example", "created_at"=>"2017-06-109T17:57:55.149-05:00", "article"=>{"title"=>"example", "slug"=>"example", "content"=>"<p>the section exists.</p>", "created_at"=>"2017-06-109T17:57:55.149-05:00", "section_id"=>"1"}}
  Section Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."slug" = $1 ORDER BY "sections"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["slug", "1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Section Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "articles" ("title", "slug", "content", "is_published", "created_at", "updated_at", "section_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "example"], ["slug", "example"], ["content", "<p>the section exists.</p>"], ["is_published", "f"], ["created_at", "2017-11-24 12:05:06.175751"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-24 12:05:06.175751"], ["section_id", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
Completed 201 Created in 38ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)
```

In my `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
```

My model has no extra methods/callbacks that would ruin the request. It only contains relationships. I don't know if this is relevant, but I saw it in a GitHub issue somewhere: articles and users are in a many2many with an authorships model, and I use devise to authenticate users.

In conclusion, the app is receiving the `created_at` param just fine, but it is overridden with the default timestamp. If I set `record_timestamps` to false, the `created_at` just becomes `nil`.

Why is my `created_at` just seemingly ignored?

Rails 5.1, Ruby 2.4.2, Postgres 10.1

Comment: `2017-06-109T17:57:55.149-05:00` is not a valid timestamp. As far as I know june does not have 106 days :D

Comment: Oh my god...that was the issue. This is what sleep deprivation does. Thank you so much I feel so stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by max: there was a syntatical error in my timestamp. It was not valid, and was ignored by Rails.

Comment: Its a bit tricky since it fails silently. If you want you can declare a custom setter and try to pass the value to `DateTime.parse` which will raise an exception if its an invalid timestamp